# How to sort a table consisting of multiple TBODY tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Say there are 3 TBODY tags inside one single table containing 3,4 and 5 number of columns.
Is it possible for all the TBODIES to get sorted if any column header on say TBODY1 is clicked.
I want the whole table to get sorted , not just the columns in one particuular TBODY.
I had some reason for which I had to use multiple TBODY's inside one single table.
Can anyone guide me on this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> not just the columns in one particuular TBODY

That suggests you have a sorting routine already that has a section which *finds the tbody associated with the selected column*. Change that so it then *finds the table associated with the tbody, loops over all the tbodys, and passes each one to the sorter*.

Comment: I have used this javascript library:                                http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/                    But I guess it works only for a table with single tbody.Is there any other way out to accomplish this task?